# proper usage of lock in async socket server

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, locking

I have written an asynchronous socket server using the begin/end pattern. I am trying now to maintain an array of all connections on the server that can be interacted with via the console. To this end I have a class named `ClientSocket` which I use to store information about each connection, and the server contains an array of `ClientSocket`. Within the server there is a method named `StoreConnection` which saves the `ClientSocket` object into the first open position. Likewise there is a method named `ClearConnection` which frees up a slot in the array, and finally a method named `ListConnections` which simply writes the list of non-null connections to the console.

My question is although the server is asynchronous it is not multithreaded, so do I need to `lock` each time I am going to read or write to my `ClientSocket` array? Is there ever a chance of multiple `StoreConnection` or `ClearConnection` operations running into each other?

Consider the following code for clarification:

```
class Server
{
    private object connectionsLock = new object();
    private ClientSocket[] connections = new ClientSocket[255];

    //..other server implementation removed for brevity...

    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult state)
    {
        ...
        Socket listener = (Socket)state.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(state);

        ClientSocket client = new ClientSocket(handler);
        StoreConnection(client);
        ...
    }

    private void StoreConnection(ClientSocket client)
    {
        lock (connectionsLock) //do i need this?
        {
            for (int i=0; i<connections.Length; i++)
            {
                if (connections[i] == null)
                {
                    connections[i] = client;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    private void ClearConnection(ClientSocket client)
    {
        lock (connectionsLock)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < connections.Length; i++)
            { ... }
        }
    }
    public void ListConnections()
    {
        lock (connectionsLock)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < connections.Length; i++)
            { ... }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Yes, Yes.  Events are separate processes from main thread.  So you must lock.  I've been hepling sombody for a couple of weeks with a TCP Server. I have a method ReadWrite() in Section 2 of the code which does something similar to your locking.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471975/gps-socket-communication-concox/44673435#comment76683640_44673435

Comment: @jdweng Your comment ultimately led me to [this blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) which answered my question. If you want to make your comment an answer I will accept.

Comment: There are many errors in the article. For example the Net library (starting 3.5) re-wrote the Socket class because of bugs in the Windows implementation.  The timer tick process moves he data from/to the ethernet card, but still signal the application through events (for async), and the sync code is running as a separate process.