# Reading endpoints from config in .net core 2 preview 2

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core

I'm migrating some of my projects now that .net core 2 preview 2 is out. I have a class that inherits from ClientBase<T> and connects to some WCF services.

Is if there a recommended way to store the endpoint configuration?, for example reading the code of [NetTcpBinding](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/NetTcpBinding.cs) all the overloads that receive the name of the entry in the .config now throw an exception.

I was thinking store them in appsettings.json, use IConfigurationRoot to bind that entry with a class, create the <endpoint> configuration and inject that to ClientBase<T>

Has anyone knows a better way? or a library that already do something similar?

Thanks

Comment: End point is not important.Accept method get a new socket for each connection.You just need a unique mapping to look up each socket.You can create a Long ConnectionNumber that gives each socket a unique id.  Add connection number to the state object for the socket in the accept method.  Then create a dictionary<connectionNumber, stateobject> to identify each connection. I've been help somebody for a few weeks with project like this.See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471975/gps-socket-communication-concox/44673435#comment76683640_44673435.Code is broken into pieces since limit is 3000.