# How to structure communication between TcpListener and TcpClient after initial socket connection is made

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcpclient, tcplistener

So this is maybe pretty simple for network programming dudes but I'm a little confused about this. Let me try to ask given an example of usage.

Say I were to create a chat server with clients being able to join with a username. No accounts or passwords. Just username.

I have a working Echo Server example running that uses async calls so all that is good. Now I need to define some message handling between the client and the server.

Lets say the client now connects and it wants to get the list of connected users. How would I go about doing that?

My thought is that I create a function called BeginGetConnectedUsers and that will send message to the server. The server will then reply with a list of users but because I'm using async calls I'll now have my accept code look at the message and figure out that it is a reply from a BeginGetConnectedUsers so it will send the data to a EndGetConnectedUsers.

But I have no idea if this is a good way to do something like this?
But also with this design I'll have to pair every BeginGet function with an EndGet function. This could be made more readable with the async await style but though but that may not be preferable either.

I have no experience with how to structure the following communication between client and server when they have to start exchanging all the interesting data stuff...

And advice? Places to look? All my google searches that include the work TCPLISTENER will all show me examples of Echo Servers and I already know how to do that.

Comment: The server has a main listening sockets.  Every time a new connection is made the Async Accept method is passed a new socket.  So I normally add the new socket into a List<Socket> sockets so I have a way of sending to each client.  Event better is to make a StateObject Class which contains the Socket so you can add other properties like a name or id for each connection.

Comment: I created a complicate server with an application layer that may help.  See posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471975/gps-socket-communication-concox

Comment: Haven't visited your link yet but I'm interested in what happens after the listening server accepts the connection and the connection has been established. I already send strings back and forth from multiple clients.
I'm looking for ways on how to structure the management of the following messages. How to nicely pass objects and data between server and client. And how to do it all async.

Comment: That is why you need an application layer to process messages.  The server is a salve to the client.  So normally a client will send a command, process the command, and then send a response.  So when a command comes in the Asyn Receive need to send the message to the application layer.  Most novices simply put the application into the async receive method which can cause cross threading and timing issues.  The link I provided I add a input queue so so the application layer will process commands in a FIFO.

Comment: I'll have a look see. Thanks. I'll get back if I need some clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many posible implementations here.
I woudl implement an strategy pattern or a controller pattern. Other options are state machines (deterministic automatas) or even a simple and big switch case.

So basically you have only one function to receive the messages from the wire.
All the messages implements the same interface may be

```
IMessage<T>
{
    string Type {get;set;}
    T Data {get;set;}
}
```

So when you get the message you use the Type property to route the T Data to the actual method you want.
In a simple implementation using a controller, you anotate the controller methods with an attribute indicating the message type you want to manage:

```
class Controller
{
    [Messagetype("GetConnectedUsersResponse")]
    Response GetConnectedUsers(IEnumerable<User> users)
    {
        //...
    }

    [Messagetype("AnothermessageType")]
    Response OtherStuffToDo(....)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

When you receives the message, by using some simple reflection you dynamically call to the method wich has the attibute with the matching message type attribute.

If you dont like reflection another option (among a lot of docens else) is to use an strategy patter
So you can register some message Handlers by key in your IoC container for example.
All hadlers implement a function lets say

```
interface MessageHandler<T>
{
    Response Handle(T Data);
}
```

When you receive the message you just resolve the handler using your favourite IoC container (resolving by name is lately considered as an atipattern, so take it with a pinch of salt)

```
var handler = container.resolve(message.Type);
var response = handler.handle(message.Data);
```

In both implementations you should define how you respond (if you do) and adjust the "Response" return type (May be you just dont have response so it is void)

Comment: You may be a little bit ahead of me and too abstract... I'm new at programming in general..

I think I get what you are talking about though.