# How to use C# socket for SNI SSL support bind to one IP and support multiple domains?

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl, virtualhost, sni

I've written my own webserver in C# and it works for our company.
I've added SSL support with .NET SslStream class.
Now our problem is we are supporting SSL for our customers that has hosts in our server.

Because of lack of supporting SSL, I have to use one static IP for each domain of our customer that orders SSL certificate.

How can I use one IP/port then my C# tcp socket bind to it and support multiple domains with this same IP ?

Comment: Why did you make it static?  There are better ways of locking certificate so only one user can access at a time.  What do you mean by :lack of supporting ssl"?

Comment: @jdweng I mean universal IP (static). I mean lack of support is that, I've created low level tcp socket in c#, and socket can bind to IP and port, how could I support multiple SSL which have SNI, in my socket based webserver program?

Comment: You use Sync Listener and then capture each new connection in the Async Accept method.  A listener default to accepting up to 100 connections.  You listen to IP address IP.Any with the port number.  Every time a new connection is made the Async Accept method is passed a new socket for each client.  So I normally create a list object and add the new connection in the accept method to the list.  I have an example at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471975/gps-socket-communication-concox

Comment: @jdweng I've read wrote code. Is it really related to my question? would you explain me more? You mean that I use one process that it's socket bind to IP.Any ?

Comment: A listener/Server captures all connection to a single port number.  The Listener will create a new socket for each incoming client.  The only place to get a unique set of connected clients is in the Accept Method.  You can also get the sockets in the Receive method but then your response must be processed as part of the receive event.  What my code does is to create an application layer that does the processing.  So my receive event get incoming messages and put them into a queue for the application layer to process and send the responses.

Comment: You must bind to each socket object and the only place to do the binding is in the Asyn Accept method.

Comment: @jdweng If I do that, should I get one Ssl certificate for our company and use it for one IP and port 443 on server, but for any domain that our customers order, the see their certificate in name of our company instead of their domain.Is that ok?

Comment: You are developing a Proxy server and the Proxy doesn't have to be in a particular domain.  
A domain in this case is just a range of IP addresses.  As long as there is no firewall blocking the port number 443 you should be ok.  If port 443 is blocked you can always port forward to a port number above 1000 which is not blocked.

Comment: @jdweng OK. I will test that.

Comment: @jdweng : he's not developing a Proxy but a web server supporting SSL virtual hosting, based on domain names and not on IPs. This is technically possible with TLS SNI. Moreover, he wants to serve one different certificate for each domain he is hosting. Just trying to help, c# not being my language.

Comment: He said he has one Server so he must have one IP address for that server.  Therefore he cannot have more than one listener running.  The Domain Names still map to the same PC(IP address).  One he gets a connection he can get http headers to get Domain Names.  We are dealing with two different Network layers : Transport and Application.  The app is the http with the domains.

Comment: I just check to make sure all domains were being routed to same listener.  Found interesting article : https://www.mojoportal.com/adding-a-host-name-to-the-hosts-file-for-local-testing

Comment: @EugèneAdell Thanks for describing. I agree with you and want to add some information about my webserver.

Comment: @jdweng It's a webserver which will bind to IP and port on server and it can run multiple process on same server, that each process can bind to different IP and port.

Comment: @EugèneAdell I correct your description that I want multiple domains running on one SNI certificate that based on IP, we don't want each domain use one IP, becuase server could bind port 443 on just 1 IP.

Comment: @Hamed_gibago I wrote that comment : "SSL virtual hosting, based on domain names and not on IPs"  because this how we commonly describe your need among people with long hosting experience. Not being said, but with this in mind : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html . Questions are upvoted when they are clearly written with the good keywords, and if you check exactly what I edited, I just enhanced it and changed a tag to make it clear for all that you're talking about virtual hosting.

Comment: @EugèneAdell Thanks for your fast reply, I will study your link tomorrow in work and answer as fast as I can.Hope can find any idea to develop SNI. ;)

Comment: @Hamed_gibago I can't help you in coding C#, I'm into Java sometimes but most of the time in the network protocols and hosting security. I just came in your question to format it better then people understand better your need, and make them answer faster/better. Both good questions and answers are supposed to be rewarded, even good comments if they add value.

Comment: A listener connects to a virtual IP (IP.Any) on the PC and you can only have one listener with the same port number connecting to IP.Any.  Eugene your solution would require each domain to use a different port number.  Why create a different listener for each domain when it is not necessary.  The Apache Webpage does not say you need a different listener for each domain, just a different IP address.  All the IP are still routed to the same virual port IP.Any.

Comment: @jdweng I want to test with one test created by myself and route two domain on same IP. I think this solution will help if it works.

Comment: The PC uses standard IP routing which uses the IP address and mask.  Routing always take the best route with the most restrictive mask.  So if you have two IPs 172.100.000.23 and 172.200.000.23 with a mask of 255.255.0.0.  100 would be one domain and 200 would be the second domain.  So the domain routing is automatic when sending.  Receiving since you have the same port number all receive packets will go to same Listener for the TCP transport level.  Then when the TCP is combined into the HTTP the domain name will be different for each customer.

Comment: See : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/varunm/2013/06/18/bind-multiple-sites-on-same-ip-address-and-port-in-ssl/