# How to listen to multiple TCP ports when each one accepts multiple connections

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcplistener

I need to listen to multiple ports using TcpListener and i need TcpListener  to accept multiple connections and work with each one individually, this is the code i wrote but as you see it just listen to first port then goes to `while(true)` and listen to all the connection that comes to that port. any idea how can i how can i listen to multiple port for multiple connections?

```
   private static async Task TcpServerAsync()
    {
        try
        {

            IPAddress ip;
            if (!IPAddress.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ipAddress"], out ip))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to get IP address, service will listen for client activity on all network interfaces.");
                ip = IPAddress.Any;
            }


            foreach (Ports port in Ports.GetValues(typeof(Ports)))
            {

                Log.Info("Starting listener...");
                var tcpListener = new TcpListener(ip, (int)port);

                tcpListener.Start();
                Log.Info("Listening...");

                var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
                var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000000);


                while (true)
                {
                    TcpClient client = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                    client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionNam‌​e.KeepAlive, 1);
                    HandleByPortNumber(client, (int)port);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Info("Error Happened : " + ex + ex.InnerException);
        }
}
```

and

```
   public static void HandleByPortNumber(TcpClient client , int portNumber)
    {
        switch (portNumber)
        {
            case (int)Ports.Teltonica:
                var cw = new Teltonika.TcpClientService(client);
                ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem(x =>  ( (Teltonika.TcpClientService)x).Run(), cw);
                break;

            case (int)Ports.OBDTracker:
                break;
        }
    }
```

and

```
 public enum Ports
{
    Teltonica = 3000,
    OBDTracker = 3001
}
```

Comment: Look at msdn examples : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples.  The Listener can listen as default 100 connections on the same port.  You can open multiple Listeners and use the same async Accept/Receive method for multple listeners.  The examples are the transport layer code and does not have a good application layer.  The application layer is just responding to message received.  I helped somebody over a year ago with a complex application layer which handled multiple connections.  See next comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471975/gps-socket-communication-concox?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an implementation with the extras (logging, etc.) removed. Tested and working. The problem to solve here was how to map back from a Task to its listener and port number. Obviously, my list of port numbers won't work for you, but otherwise it should work. You would also want to replace the Tuple<> with a custom class, for better readability.

```
IDictionary<Task<TcpClient>, Tuple<int, TcpListener>> tcpListeners = new Dictionary<Task<TcpClient>, Tuple<int, TcpListener>>();

foreach (var port in Enumerable.Range(20000, 5))
{
    var tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);

    tcpListener.Start();

    var task = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
    var tcpListenerPortPair = new Tuple<int, TcpListener>(port, tcpListener);

    tcpListeners.Add(task, tcpListenerPortPair);
}

Task<TcpClient> tcpClientTask;

while ((tcpClientTask = await Task.WhenAny(tcpListeners.Keys)) != null)
{
    var tcpListenerPortPair = tcpListeners[tcpClientTask];
    var port = tcpListenerPortPair.Item1;
    var tcpListener = tcpListenerPortPair.Item2;

    tcpListeners.Remove(tcpClientTask);

    // This needs to be async. What to do with its Task?
    // It cannot be awaited here.
    var handlerTask = HandleByPortNumber(tcpClientTask.Result, port);

    var task = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

    tcpListeners.Add(task, tcpListenerPortPair);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but the server just respond the first message and don't handle the rest.
I added the HandleByPortNumber impelemntaion to the question, can you take a look?

Comment: as i understood `HandleByPortNumber` can not be an async method and it can not be awaited?

Comment: You should start a separate question regarding the socket IO handler.

Comment: As far as awaiting the IO handler, it can't be awaited in the loop because that would block the loop from continuing until its task completes. However, it needs to have a continuation set one way or another, so that the task's outcome can be observed.

Comment: I used ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem to handle the response and it works fine, sofa