# GPS Tracker GT06 Send login packet to terminal in C#

Tags: c#, .net, gps

I am implementing the GT06 GPS tracking protocol. In which i am getting login packets continuously from the terminal but i cannot receive the location data from the terminal after successfully send the login packets response to terminals. Below is the detail information.

Received String from the terminal to server:

> 78-78-0D-01-03-58-51-10-22-16-34-42-00-03-1A-8E-0D-0A

Code for send login packets response from server to terminal:

```
    string sendData = "78780501" + serialNo + "D9DC0D0A";
    Send(handler, sendData);

    private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
    {

        byte[] byteData = StringToByteArray(data);
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
    {
        int NumberChars = hex.Length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        return bytes;
    }
```

Above is the code which i am currently using but its not working for me. Every time i received the login packets instead of location data. Please guide me where i need correct the code.

Thanks,
Hiren Lad.

Comment: this solution works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471975/gps-socket-communication-concox/44673435

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add after the serialNo , the Error Check you received in the beginning.

Example: "78780501" + serialNo + ErrorCheck + "0D0A";

Answer (score -1):

checksum or errro byte is not fix it generated by using  length + protocol+serialnumber example  received hex code : 78781101035517210119626770110001001b951a0d0a
for create response of it : 78780501001b66070d0a
0501001b  error byte is  6607
generted here [https://crccalc.com/[enter](https://crccalc.com/%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZOQ2.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).