# C# TCP PortForwarder stops Listening/Rejects new connections

Tags: c#, proxy, tcpclient, portforwarding, tcplistener

I'm trying to create a TCP "Proxy" or "PortForwarder" using TcpClient and TcpListener in C#. Off of the examples on MSDN and Bruno Garcia's "Simple TCP Forwarder in C#" example (however I want to use TcpClient/Listener instead!), I was able to get a basic Listener + Client + Forwarder going. I plan to make this asynchronous in the future. The problem I am experiencing is it seems that any new connection through the Listener doesn't "connect" or gets refused.

I've tried making it asynchronous already, to avoid "blocking" of the socket. It didn't seem to make any difference. I've made sure that the port is open and there is a receiving socket where I am calling "Connect" to.

```
    public void StartProxy()
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1709);

        listener.Start();

        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        TcpClient forwarder = new TcpClient();

        client.NoDelay = true;
        forwarder.NoDelay = true;

        forwarder.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("*Server IP*"), 1992);

        while (true)
        {
            DataExchange(client, forwarder);
            DataExchange(forwarder, client);
        }
    }

    public void DataExchange(TcpClient client, TcpClient forwarder)
    {
        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

        bytesRead = client.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            forwarder.GetStream().Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
```

The first test I used was to use PSTools and ping "127.0.0.1:1709". It pings and gets a result fine for the first 32 pings - then it closes/refuses any more. EDIT: When it closes/stops accepting anymore pings, the CPU Usage of the app spikes from pretty much 0% to 12% and stays there.

The second test was actually to forward my World of Warcraft traffic through it. When the first socket/connection opens, it forwards and receives the result fine. Once the second connection opens, it never reaches it's destination. For example, the first connection is the game login and the second is the server selection. I will get a "Success" On game login, but it won't go any further.

I am a newbie to this and I appreciate any and all help to get me through this hurdle!

Comment: MSDN examples uses Sockets so there should not be any issue using TCP which inherits the socket.  To get the socket properties that are missing the TCPClient has a property "Client" and the TCPListener has a property "Server" which are really the socket class object.

Comment: Yep! I was referring to the TcpClient and TcpListener examples rather than the Socket examples! I have it going for one connection, and I can't find any other properties that could be causing this issue. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Maybe im missing something, but the question is "Why does this code only work for a single client?", because there is only a single AcceptTcpClient call. Or is the question something else?

Comment: That could be it.. Ah I think I'm just incorrectly going through some examples. I assume the best thing to do is to create a new TcpClient to accept connections if there are pending connections on the listener? I thought it would accept multiple clients given the first one 'stopped' sending data/disconnected. Not only that, but I can only find one "socket.accept" call in Bruno Garcia's example (which works really well!). How does this explain the 32-ping > stop problem though?

Comment: I don't know what ping does in this case. But if you want multiple clients at the same time then you have to store them in a list and call AcceptTcpClient again (this will block, so the actual code depends on your implementation) or if you only want a single "active" client which is able to disconnet / connect a new client then you have to add logic which checks if the current client is still connected otherwise wait/accept the next client. Im not sure which version you want in this case? I checked the Bruno example and there the Accept call is in a while loop, that supports multiple clients.

Comment: When you start a listener you create a main listening service.  Every time a new client connects the accept method is passed the socket for the new connection.  You then have to call the asyn data receive method with the new socket.  Best example is the msdn socket example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Comment: @R1PFake It's just a simple tcp ping to 127.0.0.1:1709. Let's ignore that for now, as it seems like you have nailed my problem. You're right, I must've missed out on it when going through it multiple times. Upon looking at it again properly, it also seems to create a socket for forwarding in it's loop. Do I really need to create a client(to accept) and another client(to forward) for each connection? Or is it completely possible to use multiple clients to accept and one to forward? Async of course! Is the use "State" in his example his way of creating a new, private socket with each connection?

Comment: @jdweng I didn't look at this! Thank you, the loop in the examples helps me understand this a lot better. It also says client(s) so I assume that example alone can handle multiple connections!

Comment: An asynchronous  listener automatically handles multiple connections.

Comment: @jdweng Yep! I did some more research and realised that was the case. Now I know I have practically two choices: 1. Spin up a new Thread/Task for each new client/connection OR use the asynchronous approach.. is there one you would recommend over the other? Spinning up a new thread would definitely be easier but I am more than willing to learn and work with an asynchronous approach if it is better. Thanks again!

Comment: It depends on you application layer.  If the clients talk to each other, threading is probably the wrong way to go.  I usually use async approach.  In the accept method added each client to a list<Socket> so application layer has a list of clients.  I also setup a FIFO from async read method to application layer so message can be processed in order they are received.  I did a very complicated server at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471975/gps-socket-communication-concox

Comment: @jdweng I see! That is indeed a very complicated server. I just realised you have responded to almost all the threads I've seen regarding tcp sockets! Fortunately the clients dont "talk" to each other but I make them in pairs (one for receiving one for forwarding). I managed to make a working async multi-client forwarder just then without loops! Considering my clients don't need to talk to one another (they don't need to be in a list either really), would you say sending them off on a separate Task / thread is the way to go for me?

Comment: After reading about async vs. threading, I believe async would be better. it's not a heavy or resource intensive task (just forwarding data, not massive amounts) and also it's not too many connections either. Although since it is for gaming, it is latency sensitive. I just need to implement a close of the socket if it's disconnected and a better / more graceful way to stop the forwarder.