# GPS Tracking: SOCKET PROGRAMMING :

Tags: gps, listener, socketserver, tracker

I am new to socket programming and the solution at [GPS Socket communication (CONCOX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471975/gps-socket-communication-concox/) helped me to most of the extent.

I have to track and capture all the data from all these 2500 vehicles.  The listener I used from above sends data to database in batches and not continuously.

When I check the status of listener using `netstat` for `port "8888"` on which my listener is running, I see a huge list of `CLOSE_WAIT` and `ESTABLISHED` status' in the command window.

Can anyone hep me send data from all vehicles continuously to MSSQL Database?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Make proper description of question and remove non-required words and sentence.