# How to Get GPS Devices data GT06 CONCOX Protocol over TCP connection

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

**Receiving data from GPS Device:**
I have a TCP server setup which is receiving data from various GPS Trackers (GT06). Each GPS devices initiates the request, server accepts it, and starts receiving NMEA data.
Problem Is when GPS Connect to Server  Error:"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

The problem is that I don't know how to receive data from GPS over GPRS/TCP connection.
Any suggestions?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace T1
{
        class Program
       {
    public class StateObject
    {
        public const int DEFAULT_SIZE = 1024;           //size of receive buffer

        public byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_SIZE];  //receive buffer
        public int dataSize = 0;                        //data size to be received
        public bool dataSizeReceived = false;           //received data size?
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  //received data String
        public int dataRecieved = 0;

        public Socket workSocket = null;                //client socket.
        public DateTime TimeStamp;                      //timestamp of data

        public const int BufferSize = 256;
    } //end class StateObject




    public static AutoResetEvent allDone = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    public static AutoResetEvent acceptDone = new AutoResetEvent(false);


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {



        StartListening();





   }


    public static void StartListening()
    {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        // The DNS name of the computer
        // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPAddress local = IPAddress.Parse("103.118.16.129");
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8821);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true)
            {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
                 Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        // Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        // Console.Read();

    }

    private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }
    private static void Send(Socket handler, byte[] data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        // byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        handler.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
             Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }


    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.
        allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
       new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }



    static byte[] Unpack(string data)
    {
        //return null indicates an error
        List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();

        // check start and end bytes

        if ((data.Substring(0, 4) != "7878") && (data.Substring(data.Length - 4) != "0D0A"))
        {
            return null;
        }

        for (int index = 4; index < data.Length - 4; index += 2)
        {
            bytes.Add(byte.Parse(data.Substring(index, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
        }
        //crc test
        byte[] packet = bytes.Take(bytes.Count - 2).ToArray();
        byte[] crc = bytes.Skip(bytes.Count - 2).ToArray();

        uint CalculatedCRC = crc_bytes(packet);


        return packet;
    }


    static public UInt16 crc_bytes(byte[] data)
    {
        ushort crc = 0xFFFF;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            crc ^= (ushort)(Reflect(data[i], 8) << 8);
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                if ((crc & 0x8000) > 0)
                    crc = (ushort)((crc << 1) ^ 0x1021);
                else
                    crc <<= 1;
            }
        }
        crc = Reflect(crc, 16);
        crc = (ushort)~crc;
        return crc;
    }


    static public ushort Reflect(ushort data, int size)
    {
        ushort output = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            int lsb = data & 0x01;
            output = (ushort)((output << 1) | lsb);
            data >>= 1;
        }
        return output;
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        String content = String.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket. 
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {

            if (state.buffer[3] == 1)
            {

                string input = BitConverter.ToString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead).Replace("-", "");


                Console.WriteLine("Recived {0} bytes to client.", input);

                //byte[] bytes = Unpack(input);

                //byte[] serialNumber = bytes.Skip(bytes.Length - 2).ToArray();

                //byte[] response = { 0x78, 0x78, 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0 };

                //serialNumber.CopyTo(response, 4);

                //UInt16 sendCRC = crc_bytes(response.Take(response.Length - 2).ToArray());

                //response[response.Length - 2] = (byte)((sendCRC >> 8) & 0xFF);
                //response[response.Length - 1] = (byte)((sendCRC) & 0xFF);

                //Send(handler, response);
                // handler.Send(response);
            }
            else
            {
                // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                //state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
                // more data.
                // content = state.sb.ToString();

                Console.WriteLine("Recived {0} bytes to client.", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));


                //  SaveData(content);
                // Not all data received. Get more.
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
           new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
                // }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: See my complete solution.  There is a lot of code so you have to look at multiple answers because there is a limit on size of each answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471975/gps-socket-communication-concox/44673435

Comment: I am Not able to Receive Login Message

Comment: You are only creating a listener so use for IPAddres IP.Any.  No need for 103.118.16.129. Nor ipHostInfo.AddressList[0].  AddressList[0] can be IPV4 or IPV6.  A lost of machine have index zero IPV6 and index one IPV4.  Also use AddressList is only looking at one Ethernet interface on a machine and if a machine has more than one interface the code may not work.  Using IP.Any looks at all interfaces.  Use :  IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any , 8821);

Comment: Remove the While It will cause issues.  A Listener automatically listens for more than one client connection.  Your code will execute  listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener); multiple times which will give an exception.

Answer (score 0):

@jdweng

Sir I try your Suggestion But Same problem Not Receiving any Message.

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace T1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public class StateObject
        {
            public const int DEFAULT_SIZE = 1024;           //size of receive buffer

        public byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_SIZE];  //receive buffer
        public int dataSize = 0;                        //data size to be received
        public bool dataSizeReceived = false;           //received data size?
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  //received data String
        public int dataRecieved = 0;

        public Socket workSocket = null;                //client socket.
        public DateTime TimeStamp;                      //timestamp of data

        public const int BufferSize = 256;
    } //end class StateObject

    public static AutoResetEvent allDone = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    public static AutoResetEvent acceptDone = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Write_log("StartListening");
        StartListening();

    }

    public static void StartListening()
    {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8821);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
            allDone.Reset();

            // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
            Write_log("Waiting for a connection...");
            listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);

            // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
            allDone.WaitOne();
            Write_log("allDone");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        // Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        // Console.Read();
    }

    private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private static void Send(Socket handler, byte[] data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        // byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        handler.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.
        allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
       new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);

        Write_log("ReadCallback...");
    }

    private static byte[] Unpack(string data)
    {
        //return null indicates an error
        List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();

        // check start and end bytes

        if ((data.Substring(0, 4) != "7878") && (data.Substring(data.Length - 4) != "0D0A"))
        {
            return null;
        }

        for (int index = 4; index < data.Length - 4; index += 2)
        {
            bytes.Add(byte.Parse(data.Substring(index, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
        }
        //crc test
        byte[] packet = bytes.Take(bytes.Count - 2).ToArray();
        byte[] crc = bytes.Skip(bytes.Count - 2).ToArray();

        uint CalculatedCRC = crc_bytes(packet);

        return packet;
    }

    static public UInt16 crc_bytes(byte[] data)
    {
        ushort crc = 0xFFFF;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            crc ^= (ushort)(Reflect(data[i], 8) << 8);
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                if ((crc & 0x8000) > 0)
                    crc = (ushort)((crc << 1) ^ 0x1021);
                else
                    crc <<= 1;
            }
        }
        crc = Reflect(crc, 16);
        crc = (ushort)~crc;
        return crc;
    }

    static public ushort Reflect(ushort data, int size)
    {
        ushort output = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            int lsb = data & 0x01;
            output = (ushort)((output << 1) | lsb);
            data >>= 1;
        }
        return output;
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        String content = String.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket.
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        Write_log(bytesRead.ToString());

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            if (state.buffer[3] == 1)
            {
                string input = BitConverter.ToString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead).Replace("-", "");

                Console.WriteLine("Recived {0} bytes to client.", input);

                //byte[] bytes = Unpack(input);

                //byte[] serialNumber = bytes.Skip(bytes.Length - 2).ToArray();

                //byte[] response = { 0x78, 0x78, 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0 };

                //serialNumber.CopyTo(response, 4);

                //UInt16 sendCRC = crc_bytes(response.Take(response.Length - 2).ToArray());

                //response[response.Length - 2] = (byte)((sendCRC >> 8) & 0xFF);
                //response[response.Length - 1] = (byte)((sendCRC) & 0xFF);

                //Send(handler, response);
                // handler.Send(response);
            }
            else
            {
                // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                //state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read
                // more data.
                // content = state.sb.ToString();

                Console.WriteLine("Recived {0} bytes to client.", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                //  SaveData(content);
                // Not all data received. Get more.
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
                // }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Write_log(string logx)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        string rootPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);

        sb.Append(logx);

        // flush every 20 seconds as you do it
        File.AppendAllText(rootPath + "//log.txt", sb.ToString());
        sb.Clear();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @jdweng Still Not Receiving Login Message