# Concox GT800 / Wetrack800 GPS device data decoding

Tags: python-3.x, gps, twisted

I'm using twisted python tcp server

I encoded the byte string with

```py
byte.hex()
```

`data_1 = 78 78 11 01 0 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 80 00 21 21 00 00 38 54 0d0a`

`data_2 = 78 78 11 01 0 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 80 00 21 21 00 32 2a c5 0d0a`

`7878 -> Start bit`

`11 -> Packet length`

`01 -> Protocol Number`

`XX..XX -> IMEI`

`0d0a -> End bit`

I find problem in decoding this part `8000212100322ac5` according to their documentation its a login packet and I should send some response to it.

For C# [GPS Socket communication (CONCOX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471975/gps-socket-communication-concox)

I'm in need of algorithm or a decoding method in python

Comment: The question you're trying to ask here isn't clear.  Can you try again?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example might help you formulate your question more clearly.

Comment: I figured it out 0032-> serial number 2ac5 --> error code I returnded these as mentioned in documentation https://edoc.pub/communication-protocol-et130gt02egt300gt800v10-1-pdf-free.html and got the gps data

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem.  I voted to close because even though you have solved the problem, the question is still not answerable as written.

Comment: Its okay. I just asked for the decoding  procedure with the above data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For GT-800 this i think this will help you

```
class TcpGpsReceiver(protocol.Protocol):
    """ Event driven callback handler
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor
        """
        self.imei_no = ''

    def gt_800(self, decoded_data):
        """ Decode the GT-800 Device Data
        """
        if decoded_data[4:6].decode() == '11': # Check if login
            print('Login')
            self.imei_no = decoded_data[9:24]
            data = codecs.decode('7878050100059FF80D0A', encoding='hex', errors='strict')
            self.transport.write(data)
        if decoded_data[4:6].decode().upper() == '0A':
            print('Heat beat received')
            serial_number = hex(int(decoded_data[18:22], 16))[2:]
            data = codecs.decode('78780513{}670E0D0A'.format(get_serial_number(serial_number)),
                                 encoding='hex', errors='strict')
            print(decoded_data[18:22], ' -> serial number')
            self.transport.write(data)
        if decoded_data[4:6].decode() == '22':
            print('Decoding')
            s_no = hex(int(decoded_data[66:70], 16))[2:]
            date_time = decoded_data[8:20]
            latitude = int(decoded_data[23:30], 16) / 1800000
            longitude = int(decoded_data[31:38], 16) / 1800000

            timestamp = datetime(year=int(date_time[0:2], 16),
                                 month=int(date_time[2:4], 16),
                                 day=int(date_time[4:6], 16),
                                 hour=int(date_time[6:8], 16),
                                 minute=int(date_time[8:10], 16),
                                 second=int(date_time[10:12], 16)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

            location = dict(device_id=self.imei_no.decode(), imei=self.imei_no.decode(), timestamp=timestamp,
                            location=[latitude, longitude],
                            speed=0, course=0, state=0, altitude=0)
            print(location)
            # Code to access location data
            self.imei_no = ''
            self.transport.loseConnection()
        if decoded_data[6:8].decode().upper() == '8A':
            print('Date time requested')
            s_no = hex(int(decoded_data[8:12], 16))[2:]
            now = datetime.now()
            month_hex = '0' + hex(now.month)[2:]
            print(decoded_data[12:16], hex(int(decoded_data[12:16], 16))[2:])
            date_string = '{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(hex(int(str(now.year)[2:]))[2:], month_hex, return_date_hex(now.day),
                                                    return_date_hex(now.hour), return_date_hex(now.minute),
                                                    return_date_hex(now.second),
                                                    get_serial_number(s_no), get_serial_number(hex(int(decoded_data[12:16],
                                                                                                       16))[2:]))
            print(date_string)
            data = codecs.decode('78780B8A{}0D0A'.format(date_string), encoding='hex', errors='strict')
            self.transport.write(data)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        """ Called when data is received across a transport
        """
        decoded_data = codecs.encode(data, encoding='hex', errors='strict')
        print(datetime.now())
        self.gt_800(decoded_data)

def get_serial_number(s_no):
    """Decoding serial No
    """
    if len(s_no) == 1:
        return '000' + s_no
    if len(s_no) == 2:
        return '00' + s_no
    if len(s_no) == 3:
        return '0' + s_no
    if len(s_no) > 4:
        return '0000'
    return s_no

def retrun_date_hex(data):
    print(data)
    if len(str(hex(data)[2:])) == 2:
        return hex(data)[2:]
    else:
        return '0' + hex(data)[2:]

class TcpGpsReceiverFactory(protocol.Factory):
    """ Persistent configuration information, inherits from protocol.Factory
    """
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        """ Creates a protocol for each new connection
        """
        return TcpGpsReceiver()

if _name_ == '_main_':
    # Called when the module ran directly
    reactor.listenTCP(10206, TcpGpsReceiverFactory())
    reactor.run()
```

Comment: Thank you I got all the basic data needed, but the time stays same

Comment: May be previous data from device internal storage check it out