# Polling a StreamSocket connection UWP Server

Tags: c#, networking, uwp

I'm writing a TCP Server as a UWP app in C# and want to poll a list of clients to check for messages. The client list is a list of StreamSockets.

In regular C#, I can just check the NetworkStream to see if data is available. Is there a way of dong this in UWP? I am currently using:

```
mClient.InputStream.ReadAsync(streamBuffer, MessageHeader.HEADER_LENGTH, InputStreamOptions.None).AsTask().Wait(//Some amount of ms);
```

This is poor, as for many clients then the delay is going to become too high. There also seems to be a race condition, that unless the total read amount has been met, the task still fails to complete.

I'm looking for something semantically identical to this:

```
if (mNetworkStream.DataAvailable)
{
    mClient.Client.Receive(mBuffer, 1, SocketFlags.Peek);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: One listener is used for each port and can accept multiple clients on the same listener.You can use an Async listener and create a static List<TcpClient>.In the accept method as a new connection is made add each new socket to the list object.I like using  a state object that contains the socket, receive buffer, and receive message so you can enumerate through the list to see when data is available.I create a FIFO in the Data Receive method to application layer can check FIFO for new data from clients. See my project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471975/gps-socket-communication-concox

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so a bit more context to this. I am using Unity, and didn't realise that since the introduction of the IL2CPP scripting backend, that the System.Net.Sockets can be used in UWP. This means that I don't have to use any of the restrictive UWP socket wrappers.

Thanks @jdweng, I started to implement the multiple listener variation until I found out that I can use my existing .Net implementation!